# $A$ and $B$ are independent implies $A$ and $B \cap C$ are independent?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> Let $A$ and $B$ be two independent events, i.e. 
>   $ \mathbb{P}[A \cap B] = \mathbb{P}[A]\mathbb{P}[B]$.
>
> Is it true that $A$ and $B \cap C$ are also independent $\forall$ event $C$ ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

Not true.  Counterexample: $C=A\cap B$, then $A\cap C=A\cap B$, while $(B\cap C)=C$ so $P(A\cap C)=P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$, not $P(A)P(C)$, since $P(C) \lt P(B)$.

Answer (score 1):

No Take $C=A^{c}$. Then $P(A\cap (B\cap C))=0$. But $P(A)P(B\cap C)=P(A)P(B\setminus A)$ can be $>0$. In fact it is $\frac 1 8$ if $P(A)=P(B)=\frac 1 2$.

For example take $A$ and $B$ to be the events of getting heads in two independent tosses of  a fair coin.

Answer (score 1):

No. Let $B$ be the whole space, so that $P[B]=1$. Then $A$ and $B$ are independent, but $A$ and $B\cap C=C$ are not necessarily independent.